# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS with Radeon HD 6670 Screen is white

Tags: server, 18.04, graphics, radeon, white-screen

I did a clean install of Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS and the terminal is off-white with light grey text. I suspect it is something to do with my GPU with is Radeon HD 6670 but I cannot seem to exactly figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that runs into the same issue.

Use [boot-repair-disk.iso](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) and using Etcher (for MacOS) or Rufus (for Windows) create a bootable USB with the ISO.

After you boot from the bootable USB, simply reinstall GRUB and the graphics are rendered as expected. I believe GRUB is installed fresh without any extra settings which reverts the issue from default GRUB settings within the latest Ubuntu installation.

Also comparing the GRUB config file (**/etc/default/grub**), I noticed these lines have changed:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

I cannot guarantee if changing the settings to this helps, but reinstalling the GRUB from boot-repair definitely resolved the issue.